# How do I add a single instance of an item from a List to a Cart List that show the quantity of that particular item using riverpod?

Tags: flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-riverpod, riverpod-generator

[This image show List of Added items in the CartList, pressing the "--" or "+" does not reflect on the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbB9E.png) [This second image shows the quantity of the same Item after I manually rebuild the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22VIX.png)**Say I have two Lists: **
List of Products from API List A [];
Empty CartList where products from List A above can be added to CartList once and increment the quantity if it has already existed in the CartList;
**Example**
1: List of items from the API [productA, productB, productC....];
2. Add an element from a list in 1 above if it does not exist in CartList before:- CartList = [productA];
3. If it already exist in CartList increase the quantity only and make it Single instance in the CartList like this: CartList = [productA(1),productB(5)...];
This code works fine but it doesn't update the UI except if I leave the page and open it again which not what I want.
This is the code below:

//This Code add the product to the CartList

```
Consumer(
    builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
      return DefaultButton(
        onTap: () {
          ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).addToCart(product);
          context.pushRoute(
            const MyCartScreen(),
          );
        },
        text: "Add to cart",
      );
    },
  ),
```

//This increase the count quantity of the product in the CartList

```
AddRemoveWidget(
      count: "$productCount",
      productDecrement: () {
        ref
            .read(cartProvider.notifier)
            .removeFromCart(index);
      },
      productIncrement: () {
        ref
            .read(cartProvider.notifier)
            .addToCart(
                cartItems[index].product!);
      },
    ),
```

//This the StateNotifier

```
class CartList extends StateNotifier<List<CartItemModel>> {
 CartList() : super([]);

//Add Product to Cart
  void addToCart(Product product) {
    // check it product is int the list
    final isInList = state
        .where((element) => element.product!.sId == product.sId).isNotEmpty;
    if (isInList) {
      final p =
          state.where((element) => element.product!.sId == product.sId).first;
      p.quantity += 1;
      // final count = state.where((element) => element.product!.sId == product.sId).length;
      // final p = state.where((element) => element.product!.sId == product.sId).first;
      // p.quantity = count;
      final index = state.indexOf(p);
      final items = state;
      items[index] = p;
      state = items;
    } else {
      state = [...state, CartItemModel(product: product)];
    }
  }


void removeFromCart(int index) {
    // check it product is int the list
    final item = state[index];
    if (item.quantity == 1) {
      // remove it from the list of cart items
      state = state
          .where((element) => element.product!.sId != item.product!.sId)
          .toList();
    } else {
      item.quantity -= 1;
      state[index] = item;
    }
  }

}

final cartProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CartList, List<CartItemModel>>(
  (ref) => CartList(),
);
```

Comment: your `productCount` it is `ref.watch(cartProvider)` for widget `AddRemoveWidget`? And check with use `print` or debug, that your list is a new object every time it changes. And I'm also confused by this point - `state = items;`. To be more sure, it is better to do so - `state = List.of(items)`

Comment: what I am asking for is not productCount of the Api List but the (productCount) or CartItemModel.quantity of a single product in the api List.  This works but I doesn't update unless I refresh the UI myself while the AddRemoveWidget has already increase or decrease the quantify yet it doesn't reflect on the UI unless I refresh the UI myselft either by leaving the page and revisit again or by using hot reload. **final productCount = ref.watch(cartProvider);
                        final productCount = cartItems[index].quantity;**

Comment: I hear you. Can you create a minimally reproducible "copy-run" example? I could check it out.